# Radical and Galois Field Extension has degree $2^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I want to show that for $\mathbb{Q} \lt K \lt \mathbb{R}$ and $K:\mathbb{Q}$ a radical and galois field extension, then $|K:\mathbb{Q}|=2^n$. A hint was to use the proof in the attached image but I can't see where to start and how I can use the other proof.

(Sorry for the bad quality photo, there is no pdf version.)

[image]

Comment: The same question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540325/degree-of-a-galois-and-radical-field-extension). It has an answer.

Comment: I would rather an answer linked to the proof in the image if at all possible

Comment: We can introduce the chain what the proof begins with, because $K:F$ is radical, i.e. built up using extensions by elements of the form $\sqrt[k]\alpha$. Here take the prime decomposition of $k$   to obtain a chain of subfields with the given property.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you use the shown proof up until the end of the second paragraph, so $K_i$ contains all roots of $ x^{p_i}-\beta_i $. Since your $K$ is a subfield of the reals this requires that $p_i=2$, this is because otherwise at least two of the roots of $ x^{p_i}-\beta_i $ will be outside of the reals. Then every $\alpha_i$ has minimal polynomial $x^2-\beta_i$ over $K_{i-1}$, so $\mid K_i:K_{i-1} \mid = 2$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$.

This means that using the Tower Law, $$\mid K : \mathbb{Q} \mid = \mid K_n : K_{n-1} \mid \cdot \ldots \cdot \mid K_1 : K_0 \mid = 2^n$$

Therefore $ \mid K : \mathbb{Q} \mid $ is a power of $2$ as required.