# Radical and Galois Finite Field Extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

My question is for  $\mathbb{Q} \lt K \lt \mathbb{R}$ show that $|K:\mathbb{Q}|$ is a power of 2.

I know you have to use the definitions of radical and galois extensions but I don't understand how you are going to manipulate them to obtain a basis of $\mathbb{Q}$ with $2^n$ elements over $K$.

A similar question is asked here however it asks for a proof with respect to another proof whereas I will accept any method.
[Radical and Galois Field Extension has degree $2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2541500)

Comment: Why did you delete the same question, which had an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540325/degree-of-a-galois-and-radical-field-extension)? Please show some of your work or approach.

Comment: First off, I didn't delete the question, a moderator did and secondly the answer was based on a proof from a book I could not get access to without paying a large sum of money

Comment: I haven't made any inroads into the problem, I just have the definitions of a radical and galois field extension and I don't know where to go from then on. I know my aim is to provide a basis with degree $2^n$ but I don't know how to get from one to the other

Comment: What radical? Your question doesn’t say anything about radical. Please reframe it so that we can see what is being asked.

Comment: Sorry a radical field extension https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_extension see definition here